# Is there more simple/pythonic way to write this?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, nested

I want to make my code faster. And I am wondering if I can write this part of the code in a more pythonic way or a one-liner so it will be faster a bit.

Fist I try to remove all empty values from a nested dictionary with

```
def remove_empties_from_dict(combined_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in combined_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = remove_empties_from_dict(v)
        if v is not None:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict or None
```

If I try a one liner  `dict((k, v) for k, v in combined_dict.iteritems() if v)` it only deletes none values in last values, not in whole set of nested dictionary. Example:

```
combined_dict = {1: {'a': {}, 'b': {}}, 2: {'c': {100: None}}, 3: {'d: {}, 'f': {1007: {'random_stirng': u'random_intiger'}
```

I want `combined_dict = {3: 'f': {1007: {'random_stirng': u'random_intiger'}` with a one-liner.

The second point is I want to transform nested dictionary to a list, so I can transform it to data frame more efficiently. I cooked up this code.

```
 new_list = []
for k1 in remove_empties_from_dict(combined_dict):
     curr_dict = remove_empties_from_dict(combined_dict)[k1]
     for k2 in curr_dict:
         curr_dict_2=curr_dict[k2]
         for k3 in curr_dict_2:
             curr_dict_3=curr_dict_2[k3]
             for k4 in curr_dict_3:
                 curr_dict_4=curr_dict_3[k4]
                 new_dict= {'c0':k1, 'c1': k2, 'c2': k3, 'c3': k4, 'c4': curr_dict_4}
                 new_list.append(new_dict)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do - can you [edit] into your post some example inputs and their corresponding outputs?

Comment: " a one liner so it will be faster a bit" one-liner does not imply faster

Comment: This might also be a candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Oh thanks I didnt know that exists. Cheers!